# $\wedge^k(V)^* \cong \mathrm{Alt}^k(V)$

Tags: linear-algebra, exterior-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional real vector space, let $\mathrm{Alt}^k(V)$ denote the space of 
alternating $k$-linear forms on $V$ and let $\wedge^k(V)$ denote the $k^{th}$ exterior power of $V$.
I am trying to see why the algebraic dual $\wedge^k(V)^* := (\wedge^k(V))^*$ is isomorphic to  $\mathrm{Alt}^k(V)$. Here are
my thoughts:

By the universal property of the exterior power, for any alternating $k$-linear form $f$ 
with domain $V^k$ there exists a unique linear form $\phi$ with domain $\wedge^k(V)$ such that 
$$
\phi(v_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge v_k) = f(v_1, \dots, v_k).
$$
The universal property thus provides a mechanism to produce elements in $\wedge^k(V)^*$ 
from elements in $\mathrm{Alt}^k(V)$ and this mechanism of production is unique.

Thus, we have an injection
$$
\Phi: \mathrm{Alt}^k(V) \longrightarrow \wedge^k(V)^*
$$

What I'm not sure about is how to argue surjectivity; what is the best way to approach this?

Comment: Since everything is finite dimensional, you can just count dimensions to show surjectivity.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 Yes, I see this, but counting the dimensions of these spaces is a fair amount of work. One has to pick bases, show that they are, in fact, bases and then count....Is there a more direct way from the universal property to do this that doesn't involve counting?

Comment: I think the two are switched up in the paragraph that begins "The universal property..."

Comment: @ItsNotObvious I can see what the dimension of the exterior power is immediately, but not the alternating forms. I imagine that it's standard though, and if the dimensions match you are already done.

Comment: @rschwieb Yes, the dimension of both spaces, assuming $V$ is of dimension $n$, is given by $\frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!}$, but would like to prove this result without using dimension arguments, if possible...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The canonical map $\psi\colon V^k \to \bigwedge^k V$ given by $\psi(v_1, \ldots, v_k) = v_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge v_k$ is alternating. If you have an element $g \in (\bigwedge^k V)^*$ then $g \circ \psi\colon V^k \to \mathbf R$ is also alternating, and I believe that this assignment $g \mapsto g \circ \psi$ gives you an inverse to $\Phi$.

This is simpler than you might fear, and has little to do with the ground ring or the finiteness of $V$. And maybe we should expect that, since the universal property of $\bigwedge^k V$ more or less says that it [represents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representable_functor) the functor $W \mapsto L^k_a(V, W)$.

Extra trouble and hypotheses seem to enter once you try to write things such as an isomorphism $(\bigwedge^k V)^* \approx \bigwedge^k (V^*)$, an embedding $\bigwedge^k V \hookrightarrow V^{\otimes k}$, or the wedge product induced on alternating forms. Some examples of this are discussed in the back of [Fulton and Harris](http://books.google.com/books/about/Representation_Theory.html?id=6GUH8ARxhp8C).

Comment: There's a bit more to say (and check!). I'll try to find time after walking the dog/doing other stuff.

Comment: What you have said is already correct and interesting : +1. (And don't forget the ball for the dog !)

Comment: Nice; thanks for your help.